# ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host xxx at port 16313

Tags: websphere, tivoli

Getting following error on WAS8558.
This WAS8558 is being used by Netcool/OMNIbus WebGUI8.1.
I am having problems while stopping WAS and getting below error.
Earlier I had done the SSL configuration and performed steps mentioned on below link to enable TLSv1.2
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/206952/how-do-i-configure-websphere-application-server-ss.html

ERROR:

```
  8:46:59:065 EDT] 00000001 WsServerStop  A   ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exc
eption.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host xxxxx.cap.dev.net at port 16313.
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ConnectorHelper.createConnector(ConnectorHelper.java:628)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerStop.runTool(WsServerStop.java:373)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:271)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerStop.main(WsServerStop.java:113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:401)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:164)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host xxxxx.cap.dev.net at port 16313.
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:635)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.access$000(AdminClientFactory.java:127)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory$1.run(AdminClientFactory.java:210)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:63)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:206)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ConnectorHelper.tryProtocol(ConnectorHelper.java:665)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ConnectorHelper.createConnector(ConnectorHelper.java:597)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:58)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:542)
        at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClientPrivileged(AdminClientFactory.java:457)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOExce
ption: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: 
java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure]
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:429)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.(SOAPConnectorClient.java:228)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: Received fatal alert:
 handshake_failure; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.io.IOException: Exception during sslSocket.startHandshake: Receive
d fatal alert: handshake_failure]
        at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:475)
        at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Call.java:510)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:387)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:372)
        ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 1):

### try these Solutions

1- write "xxxxx.cap.dev.net:16313/soap" on the browser and hit enter to check if your problem relevant to firewall or not.

if you get a reply, we become to ensure that your problem is not a firewall problem.

2- ensure that the certificate has not been expired

3- in some cases, SOAP connector does not work with TLSv1.2, but it works with v1.

4- try to work with eclipse instead of IBM integration designer.

Comment: 2) No, the certificates are not expired.

Not sure on point 3 & 4.
  
Additional Info, The product which I am working is a IBM product(netcool/omnibus webgui8.1) which is using the WAS8.5.5.8.
I am not very familiar with SOAP.

On Server side I can see, the port is in Listen Mode
netstat -na | grep -i 16313
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16313               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: 1)I tried following https://xxx:16313/soap
I get below output,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:ns0="admin" ns0:JMXMessageVersion="1.0.0" ns0:JMXVersion="1.2.0" /> 
- <SOAP-ENV:Body>
- <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode> 
 <faultstring>xxxxxx</faultstring> 
  <faultactor>/soap</faultactor> 
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>